# Convert while-loop to mathematical formula

Tags: c++, c, loops, math, iteration

I have following *loop* as a inner loop and try to get rid of it by transforming it into a mathematical formula:

```
while(!(((aux = a * b) <= c) && (c >= aux + d))) --a;
```

`a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `aux` are all of type `size_t`, i.e. `unsigned int`'s

*NOTE:* **`a`** is decremented in every iteration within the loop's body!

I'm totally stuck at this problem. I tried to simplify the loop condition, but failed because of the `unsigned`ness constraint.

As result I just want to get the value of **`a`** depending on `b`, `c`, `d`.

Comment: Isn't it UB? Assigning `aux` and using it on the same expression before sequence point (Not sure I am understanding it good enough..)? Update, OK, it is not. We have `&&` here

Comment: @EugeneSh. isn't there a seq point at the `&&`, is that's what you're telling?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yeah, it is.

Comment: @EugeneSh. i already checked the sequence points. It works, but it should not matter in deriving the mathematical formula.

Comment: You are not telling us the initial values of `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`

Comment: @EugeneSh. does this matter? I want it as general as possible.

Comment: If a,b,c,d unsigned, than one of the relations seems redundant. if aux<=c-d no need to check also aux <= c.

Comment: @HeikoSchäfer: Hint: `c - aux >= d` = `c >= aux + d`, unless there's an integer overflow.

Comment: @HeikoSchäfer If you want the answer to be as general as possible don't tag your post with programming languages which define specific semantics for the operations you want translated.

Comment: ok, I'll give the comments of @simon and Zeta a try and update the question if it seems to work.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I want the **formula** as general as possible, i.e. working for all positive or null integers

Comment: I order to improve my future questions: what was the reson to put my question to **-1**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `aux` with `a*b` at every point, and you get:

```
    !(a * b <= c && c - a * b >= d)
<=> !(a * b <= c && c >= d + a * b)
<=> !(a * b <= c && d + a * b <= c)
```

If `d` is greater than `c`, the second condition will be false and therefore the loop will never terminate. So we can consider only `d <= c`. The second condition is stricter, so we can focus on that solely:

```
<=> !(d + a * b <= c)
<=> !(    a * b <= c - d)
<=> !(    a     <= (c - d)/b) // if integer division is used
<=>  (    a     >  (c - d)/b)
```

Given that you only decrement `a`, it either needs to fulfil the condition `(a <= (c - d)/b)` right from the beginning or be less than or equal to `(c - d)/b`. Overall we get:

```
a = std::min(a, (c - d)/b);
```

Comment: @HeikoSchäfer: Yeah, but my reasoning was off for `d > c`. In this case you would end up with a non-terminating loop.

Comment: I'll tested it in my application and it works exactly as I expect it, i.e. passes all tests :)

Answer (score 5):

Let's simplify:

```
while(!(((aux = a * b) <= c) && (c - aux >= d))) --a;
```

Drop `aux` in favor of just `a*b`:

```
while(!((a*b <= c) && (c - a*b >= d))) --a;
```

Rewrite the `!(x && y)` into `!x || !y`:

```
while ((a*b > c) || (c - a*b < d)) --a;
```

Flip the sign on the second expression:

```
while ((a*b > c) || (a*b > c - d)) --a;
```

Which is just:

```
while (a*b > min(c, c-d)) --a;
```

Which is to say, find the smallest `a` such that `a*b <= min(c, c-d)`. Unless it's already smaller than that. So:

```
a = min(a, min(c, c-d) / b);
```

Er, given that all the variables are `unsigned`, obviously `min(c, c-d) == c - d`, so:

```
a = min(a, (c-d)/b);
```

Comment: I have to admit, this answer is suberb, too :)